# create new variable based on a regular expression

Tags: regex, r

My question involves how to create a new variable on a data frame in R based on the result of a regular expression. 
Below is a minimal example of the data:

```
df <- data.frame(model=c("Legacy 2.0  BG5 B4 AUTO","Legacy 2.0 BH5 AT","Legacy 2.0i CVT Non Leather","Legacy 2.0i CVT","Legacy 2.0 BL5 AUTO B4",
                 "Legacy 2.0 BP5 AUTO","Legacy 2.0 BM5 AUTO CVT"), CRSP=c(3450000,3365000,4950000,5250000,4787526,3550000,5235000))

df
                        model    CRSP
1     Legacy 2.0  BG5 B4 AUTO 3450000
2           Legacy 2.0 BH5 AT 3365000
3 Legacy 2.0i CVT Non Leather 4950000
4             Legacy 2.0i CVT 5250000
5      Legacy 2.0 BL5 AUTO B4 4787526
6         Legacy 2.0 BP5 AUTO 3550000
7     Legacy 2.0 BM5 AUTO CVT 5235000
```

I would like to create a new variable 'chassis' whose value is the third element of the corresponding 'model' variable string, thus ending up with:

```
df
                        model    CRSP chassis
1     Legacy 2.0  BG5 B4 AUTO 3450000     BG5
2           Legacy 2.0 BH5 AT 3365000     BH5
3 Legacy 2.0i CVT Non Leather 4950000     CVT
4             Legacy 2.0i CVT 5250000     CVT
5      Legacy 2.0 BL5 AUTO B4 4787526     BL5
6         Legacy 2.0 BP5 AUTO 3550000     BP5
7     Legacy 2.0 BM5 AUTO CVT 5235000     BM5
```

I need to find a way of extracting the appropriate elements in each row and place them in the new variable. 
Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm a big fan of **tidyr** for this sort of task and extracting all the pieces into separate columns:

```
if (!require("pacman")) install.packages("pacman")
pacman::p_load(dplyr, tidyr)

regx <- "(^[A-Za-z]+\\s+[0-9.a-z]+)\\s+([A-Z0-9]+)\\s*(.*)"

df %>%
    extract(model, c("a", "chassis", "b"), regx, remove=FALSE)

##                         model           a chassis           b    CRSP
## 1     Legacy 2.0  BG5 B4 AUTO  Legacy 2.0     BG5     B4 AUTO 3450000
## 2           Legacy 2.0 BH5 AT  Legacy 2.0     BH5          AT 3365000
## 3 Legacy 2.0i CVT Non Leather Legacy 2.0i     CVT Non Leather 4950000
## 4             Legacy 2.0i CVT Legacy 2.0i     CVT             5250000
## 5      Legacy 2.0 BL5 AUTO B4  Legacy 2.0     BL5     AUTO B4 4787526
## 6         Legacy 2.0 BP5 AUTO  Legacy 2.0     BP5        AUTO 3550000
## 7     Legacy 2.0 BM5 AUTO CVT  Legacy 2.0     BM5    AUTO CVT 5235000
```

You could get a bit more generic with this regex:

```
regx <- "(^[^ ]+\\s+[^ ]+)\\s+([^ ]+)\\s*(.*)"
```

Also note you can use `extract` to get just the column you're after by dropping the grouping parenthesis on the first and last groups as follows:

```
regx <- "^[A-Za-z]+\\s+[0-9.a-z]+\\s+([A-Z0-9]+)\\s*.*"

df %>% 
    extract(model, "chassis", regx, remove=FALSE)
```

Comment: I have other preceeding and subsequent data manipulation steps on the same data frame within a **dplyr** pipe `%>%` and so this solution is more convenient as I can insert this directly into the loop. Thanks @TylerRinker

Answer (score 10):

Here's a possible solution using `stringi`

```
library(stringi)
df$chassis <- stri_extract_all_words(df$model, simplify = TRUE)[, 3]
df
#                         model    CRSP chassis
# 1     Legacy 2.0  BG5 B4 AUTO 3450000     BG5
# 2           Legacy 2.0 BH5 AT 3365000     BH5
# 3 Legacy 2.0i CVT Non Leather 4950000     CVT
# 4             Legacy 2.0i CVT 5250000     CVT
# 5      Legacy 2.0 BL5 AUTO B4 4787526     BL5
# 6         Legacy 2.0 BP5 AUTO 3550000     BP5
# 7     Legacy 2.0 BM5 AUTO CVT 5235000     BM5
```

Or similarly

```
df$chassis <- sapply(stri_extract_all_words(df$model), `[`, 3)
```

Answer (score 5):

An alternative solution using `strsplit`

```
# Split each of the models using space (the + accounts for multiple spaces)
# Note that model is a factor in your data frame, so it must be cast to char
model.split <- strsplit(as.character(df$model), " +")
# Now go through each element of the splitted list and get the 3rd word
df$chassis <- sapply(model.split, function(x){x[3]})
```

Comment: Or a similar approach using `data.table`. `setDT(df)[, chassis:=tstrsplit(model, ' +')[[3]]][]`

Answer (score 4):

We could match the character till the numeric part including the `i` and space, replace it with `''` using `sub`, and then extract the first word with `word`.

```
library(stringr)
 word(sub('^\\D*[0-9.i ]*', '', df$model),1)
#[1] "BG5" "BH5" "CVT" "CVT" "BL5" "BP5" "BM5"
```

Or match the  spaces, replace with a single space and use `word`

```
 word(gsub(' +', ' ', df$model),3)
 #[1] "BG5" "BH5" "CVT" "CVT" "BL5" "BP5" "BM5"
```

NOTE:  Not sure the extra space in the first element of 'model' is a typo.  If the original dataset do not have more than one space between words, then `word(df$model, 3)` would work.

Answer (score 3):

This can easily be done in base R:

```
transform(df, chassis=sub("^(\\S+\\s+){2}(\\S+).*", "\\2", model))
```

produces:

```
                        model    CRSP chassis
1     Legacy 2.0  BG5 B4 AUTO 3450000     BG5
2           Legacy 2.0 BH5 AT 3365000     BH5
3 Legacy 2.0i CVT Non Leather 4950000     CVT
4             Legacy 2.0i CVT 5250000     CVT
5      Legacy 2.0 BL5 AUTO B4 4787526     BL5
6         Legacy 2.0 BP5 AUTO 3550000     BP5
7     Legacy 2.0 BM5 AUTO CVT 5235000     BM5
```

Answer (score 2):

You can split on the space character using `cSplit` from the `splitstackshape` package:

```
library(splitstackshape)
df$chassis <- cSplit(df, "model", sep = " ", "wide")$model_3
```

This avoids the need for a regex or an `apply` function.

Comment: `cSplit` has an option `drop=FALSE`, and it returns a data.table.  So, may be this also would work `cSplit(df, "model", sep = " ", "wide", drop=FALSE)[, c(1,5), with=FALSE]`

Answer (score 0):

Using *unglue* we could do :

```r
# install.packages("unglue")
library(unglue)

unglue_unnest(df, model, "{=.*?} {=.*?} {chassis=[^ ]+}{=.*?}", remove = FALSE)
#>                         model    CRSP chassis
#> 1     Legacy 2.0  BG5 B4 AUTO 3450000     BG5
#> 2           Legacy 2.0 BH5 AT 3365000     BH5
#> 3 Legacy 2.0i CVT Non Leather 4950000     CVT
#> 4             Legacy 2.0i CVT 5250000     CVT
#> 5      Legacy 2.0 BL5 AUTO B4 4787526     BL5
#> 6         Legacy 2.0 BP5 AUTO 3550000     BP5
#> 7     Legacy 2.0 BM5 AUTO CVT 5235000     BM5
```